# Erro "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" e "Undefined index" no formulário PHP

Tags: php, array, foreach

Devo criar 20 inputs que quando preenchidas devem mostrar o que foi digitado nelas logo abaixo, usando arrays e foreach, eis o código abaixo:

```
function repeteInput(){
    for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++){
        echo '<form action="repeteInput.php" method="post">';
        echo 'Digite um número aqui ('.$i.')<input type="text" name "produto[]"><br>';
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Enviar"></form>';
    $produtos = $_POST['produto'];
    foreach ($produtos as $produto){
        echo $produto."<br>";
    }
}

echo repeteInput();
```

Já verifiquei o código, e ele está exatamente igual ao que eu copiei no meu caderno, que havia funcionado em outro PC. Mesmo assim, ele mostra esse erro depois da página:

```
Notice: Undefined index: produto in C:\xampp\htdocs\24.04.2017\repeteInput.php on line 8

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\24.04.2017\repeteInput.php on line 9
```

Comment: Em primeiro lugar, coloque o `<form action="repeteInput.php" method="post">` fora do laço _for_, pois varias tags `<form>` estão sendo abertas e só há uma _tag_ de fechamento.

Comment: Continua aparecendo os mesmos erros

Comment: Sim, eu sei, mas é apenas para melhorar o seu código. Afinal, é um comentário, e não uma resposta.

Comment: aproveite e poste a parte HTML por o problema é nele.

Answer (score 1):

Neste caso $produto = $_POST['produto']; não está recebendo um array, tente isto

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="test1">
    <input type="text" name="test2">
    <input type="text" name="test3">
    <input type="text" name="test4">
    <input type="text" name="test5">

    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>

<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $produto) {
        echo $produto . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

**Levando em consideração sua necessidade, eu sugiro algo assim:** 
*Obs. Entenda que isto é apenas um exemplo para lhe auxiliar no pensamento, em produção há formas melhores de fazer o que precisa.*

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <?php
        for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++)
        {
            echo "<label>Produto $i: </label>";
            echo "<input type='text' name='$i' value=''><br>";
        }

    ?>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    <hr>
</form>

<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $produto) {
        echo "Nº: " . $key. " - Produto: " .$produto . "<br>";
    }
?>
```

**Código que produz o mesmo efeito**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <?php
        for($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++)
        {
            echo "<label>Produto $i: ";
            echo "<input type='text' name='".$produto[] = $i."' value=''><br>";
        }

    ?>
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    <hr>
</form>

<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $produto) {
        echo "Nº: " . $key. " - Produto: " .$produto. "<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Fora os erros de semântica da pergunta, a solução dele ainda é melhor, pois, na verdade, `$produtos` recebe um *array* sim, pois ele definiu o `input` como `name="produtos[]"`. O erro foi causado por tentar acessar uma variável em `$_POST` sem validar se houve uma requisição `POST`. Na solução apresentada aqui, se houverem mais campos no formulário, já fica inviável, inclusive se utilizar `<input type="submit">`, pois o mesmo é enviado junto com a requisição.

Comment: Então, como citado, a ideia inicial foi apresentar uma base para que ele pudesse seguir.
Como foi dito a expressão - $produtos = $_POST['produto']; - não retorna um array, e sim input produzido por ele em - name "produto[]" - é de fato um array, tanto que apresentei na terceira ideia uma solução utilizando o método dele.